# onchange add value use java script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

onchange option value calculate price `$price` is current value and  current **option     value 0;**   if the change option value then calculate value option value is qty of product without change its **0** if we change the value is change

```
<?php 
    print_r ($_POST);
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $price=$_POST['price'];
?>

<div class="myaccount1_2">
    <div class="deal_text"><?php echo $name;  ?>.</div>
    <div class="mypurchase_1">
        <select class="select_new" name="val">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="mypurchase_1">£<?php echo $price; ?></div>
    <div class="price"><b>£00.00 </b></div>
</div>
```

i want before selection show `00.00` after the selection calculate value show

Answer (score 2):

Use below jQUery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select[name=val]").change(function(){
     var qnt = $(this).val();
     var price = "<?php echo $price;?>";
     var total = qnt*price;
     $(".price").val('<b>£'+total+'</b>');
     alert(qnt*price);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function..

```
<script>
function calculate(value,price)
{
var div = document.getElementById('div_id');
div.innerHTML=value*price;
}
</script>
<select class="select_new" name="val" **onchange="calculate(this.value,'$price')"**)>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
```